# How to convert json object into java

Tags: java, php, json

Here is my java code to get response from server.

```
    try

    {
       HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
       HttpResponse response;
       HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.def.net/my_script.php");

       response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
       HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
       String s = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

       JSONObject json = (JSONObject)new JSONParser().parse(s);
        System.out.println("News title= " + json.get("news_title"));
        System.out.println("Content= " + json.get("news_content"));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

here is what php script returns.

```
{ "desktop_app_newsfeed":
[
 { "news_id": "132",
   "news_title": "test1",
   "news_content": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Donec...", 
   "news_date": "2013-07-18 10:38:20" },

 { "news_id": "1",
   "news_title": "Hello world!",
   "news_content":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Donec...",
    "news_date": "2013-04-22 17:54:05" 
 }
 ]
 }
```

how do iterate to get thus assigned to variables in java.

Comment: Which JSON implemenation library are you using?

Comment: simple json object library.

Comment: If you mean JSON-simple -- **you're not clear** -- decoding examples are at http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/DecodingExamples. Your code mentions JSONObject, which I think may be in a different library. Is your Java code above actual code, does it compile, and, if so, what does it do?

Comment: in my Netbeans IDE i used json-simple.jar file and then i tried examples with jackson and Gson libraries. But i did not remove those libraries and kept them on classpath. But the examples i tried with were org.json and not with the org.simple. so the examples i copied into my editor showed lot of errors. I got it fixed. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since you know the structure you can simply cast the heck out of the `Object`s like so:

```
JSONObject json = (JSONObject) new JSONParser().parse(jsonString);
JSONArray feed = (JSONArray) json.get("desktop_app_newsfeed");

for (Object item : feed) {
    JSONObject news = (JSONObject) item;

    System.out.println("News title= " + news.get("news_title"));
    System.out.println("Content= " + news.get("news_content"));
}
```

If you are unsure of the structure I suggest using a debugger and inspecting what's in the `json` variable.

If you are looking for a more generic and robust approach you will have to look at the documentation like *Thomas W* pointed out in one of the comments.